# How to invoke inner-class constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

I've the following classes:

```
package org.gradle;

public class Supcl {

    public class Inner extends Supsupcl {
        public Inner(int a) {
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
package org.gradle;

public class Subcl extends Supcl.Inner {

    public Subcl() {
        Supcl.Inner.super(34); //error: No enclosing instance of type Supcl is 
                               //available due to some 
                               //intermediate constructor invocation

    }
}
```

And class `Supsupcl`:

```
package org.gradle;

public class Supsupcl {}
```

If I try to replace `Supcl.Inner.super(34);` with `super(34);` the same error will occur. How do it do?

Comment: What is type `Supsupcl`? Additionally, my Eclipse gives me the error "Supcl.Inner cannot be resolved to a variable" at `Supcl.Inner`.

Comment: @Unihedron Yes, I'm sure. It's just a class which a super class for that _Inner_. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since non-static inner classes have a special relationship with their outer class you always need an instance of the outer class to create an instance of the inner class.

In your case, where a non-inner class extends an inner class, you'll need to either create an instance of the outer class or pass it:

```
public class Subcl extends Supcl.Inner {
  public Subcl() {
    //assuming there is a no-argument constructor Supcl()
    //this only works in one statement so the call to super is still 
    //part of the first statment in this constructor
    new Supcl().super(34); //will call Inner(34)
  }

  public Subcl( Supcl sup) {
    sup.super(34);  //will call Inner(34)
  }
}
```

Note that you'd have to do this even if `Inner` had a no-argument constructor, since you need to somehow get the instance of `Supcl` and the compiler can't deduce this.

Finally a word of advise (although it is primarily my opinion): as you can see the syntax for inner classes is not always straight forward and it might be hard to grasp what's going on in some cases,  thus I'd suggest using inner classes only in simple cases and only if you really need them. It will make your life a lot easier :)

Answer (score 6):

You are referencing an inner class nested to the instance of `Supcl`, so the right idiom to initialize the inner class is:

```
new Supcl().new Inner(int i)
(assuming Supcl has a 0-argument constructor or the default constructor)
```

You cannot invoke `super` outside the constructor, so you'll have to invoke it as the first line of your `Inner(int i)` constructor code.

Comment: `super()` is implicitly called in `Inner(int i)` so there's no need to do that. Besides, it wouldn't help much.

Comment: @Thomas you are right, but OP wanted to invoke parametrized `super`, while what is invoked implicitly is `super()`.

Answer (score 1):

Make the inner `static`

```
public static class InnerClass {

}
```

and access it like

```
ParentClass.InnerClass innerClass = new ParentClass.InnerClass(args);
```

where `args` is your custom parameters if you have any